# Case statement in where clause w/an OR

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, case-statement

Apologies in advance since I feel like I'm probably forgetting/missing something obvious on this one.  Here goes; I'm using a case statement in my WHERE clause, the below works fine:

```
WHERE r.[SomeCol] = @SomeColVal
AND SomeOtherCol =  
(
CASE WHEN (@Year = 0 AND @Period = 0) THEN
@SomeVal
     WHEN...
...
     ELSE
@SomeVal
END
```

My "issue" is that I want to add an additional OR clause to my ELSE block..something like this:

```
WHERE r.[SomeCol] = @SomeColVal
AND SomeOtherCol =  
(
CASE WHEN (@Year = 0 AND @Period = 0) THEN
@SomeVal
     WHEN...
...
     ELSE
@SomeVal OR @SomeVal - 1
END
```

Naturally, this throws this error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'. within the ELSE statement

Hence my question...what is the correct/alternate logic I can use to accomplish this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is an expression that returns one value. Instead of testing against the single `CASE` expresssion, you could do an OR between two, that only difference is the else clause. (Using `IN` as a shortcut for writing `SomeOtherCol = ... OR SomeOtherCol =`) You could do:

```
WHERE r.[SomeCol] = @SomeColVal
AND SomeOtherCol in   
    (CASE WHEN (@Year = 0 AND @Period = 0) THEN
        @SomeVal
        CASE WHEN...
            ...
        CASE ELSE
        @SomeVal END,
    CASE WHEN (@Year = 0 AND @Period = 0) THEN
        @SomeVal
        CASE WHEN...
            ...
        CASE ELSE
        @SomeVal - 1 END)
```

My guess is this has more logic than you need, and if the specifics of your situation were known a much simpler and clearer else statement could be written.